# Meteor package naming error

Tags: meteor, sass, package, directory

**I've been working on a Meteor package** for some time now and I have been been using a Meteor `SCSS` build package to compile my sass. Now for reasons like `autoprefixer` and such, I need to compile the SCSS outside of Meteor. My plan was  to use `Codekit` but when I try to build the SCSS I get an error with no message at all. When I use the Sublime Text 2 SCSS build package I get an error as well. I have come to the conclusion  that this is because of my Meteor package name. I have named it:

> myusername:packagename

and as a folder that translates to

> myusername/packagename

It replaces `:` with `/` and because of that, Codekit thinks the folder named `myusername/packagename` is two folders `myusername -> packagename.` That messes up the folder tree when Codekit tries to compile it.

**Is there a good way to handle this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, you can rename the directory of the package and then add an entry inside the `Package.describe` call in `package.js`:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "My package",
  version: "0.0.1",
  name: "myusername:packagename"
});
```

Now, the name of the package will be read from `package.js` and the directory can be called whatever you want.